# An alternative of projective dimension in triangulated categories

Tags: category-theory, homology-cohomology, abelian-categories, triangulated-categories

Does anybody know anything about an alternative of the notion of projective dimension (defined in abelian categories with enough projective objects) in triangulated categories?